# Can you check for multiple blanks before running function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to setup a script that only runs when 3 particular columns have a string AND when a 4th as "Yes" in it. With the statement below, every time any of the fields are changes OR the approved column is changed to "Yes", it runs the script. It also isn't supposed to run if the current row being edited is the first row.

```
function onEditIntake() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var approved = s.getRange(row,10).getDisplayValue();
  var iproject = s.getRange(row,7).getDisplayValue();
  var assignee = s.getRange(row,8).getDisplayValue();
  var deadlineDate = s.getRange(row,9).getDisplayValue();

  if (iproject != null && assignee != null && deadlineDate != null && row != "1" && approved != "Yes") {
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**To Clarify**: Every time any of the fields are changed, the rest of the script runs. I only want it to run when all of the IF conditions are met.

**Update**: I've changed the code to as you can see below. It's not triggering the If statement with every edit now. However, any time the "Yes" statement is provided for approved, it starts the script regardless of if the other fields are empty, null, "", or any other variety of nothing.

```
function onEditIntake() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var row = r.getRow();
  var approved = s.getRange(row,10).getDisplayValue();
  var iproject = s.getRange(row,7).getDisplayValue();
  var assignee = s.getRange(row,8).getDisplayValue();
  var deadlineDate = s.getRange(row,9).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log("Approved: " + approved);
  Logger.log("Project: " + iproject);
  Logger.log("Deadline: " + deadlineDate);
  Logger.log("Assignee: " + assignee);
  if ((iproject != " ") && (assignee != " ") && (deadlineDate != " ") && (row != "1") && (approved == "Yes")) {
```

Comment: Where are you checking for `Yes`? You're just checking if `approved` is not `null`, so it could be `Yes` or `No`.

Comment: What does `console.log(approed, iproject, assignee, deadlineDate);` show when this happens?

Comment: @Barmar I'm fairly new to this, but the script doesn't seem to like console.log. Just some quick googling seems to point to needing to use logger for google scripts?

Comment: @Barmar I've also since tested with approved == "Yes" and the rest of the script runs when anything is entered into any of the other values.

Comment: You probably should be using `""`, not `" "` -- an empty field doesn't have a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is a bit faster:

```
function onEditIntake() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = s.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var values = s.getRange(row, 7, 1, 4).getDisplayValues();

  var approved = values[0][3];
  var iproject = values[0][0];
  var assignee = values[0][1];
  var deadlineDate = values[0][2];

  if ((iproject != "") && (assignee != "") && (deadlineDate != "") && (row != 1) && (approved == "Yes")) {
    Logger.log('should run')
  }
}
```

Notice how there is 1 getDisplayValues() call as opposed to 4 separate getDisplayValue() calls. It won't make that big a deal in this script but is something to consider in future.